# É possível criar um Options Menu sem uma Action Bar no Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbar

Eu estou criando uma tela de Perfil, e gostaria de pôr um Options Menu com as opções 'Editar perfil' e 'Sair'. O problema é que eu não possuo uma Action Bar nessa tela, e nem quero colocar uma, mas gostaria de criar esse Options Menu no canto superior direito da tela. Isso é possível? Como posso fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o XML dessa tela está dessa forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/greylight"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background_profile">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/profile"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Caíque Araujo"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="21sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Universidade Federal do Ceará"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use uma toolbar, que pode ser colocada em qualquer lugar do código, e você pode inflar um menu nela. Mas do jeito que você quer fazer, pode colocar uma actionbar transparente, e fazer com que o conteudo apareça atrás dela, ou ainda aumentar o padding superior e inferior da imagem para o tamanho da actionbar transparente (56dp)

Comment: Você pode usar o Pop Menu
[só seguir a descrição deste post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21329225/4395789)